# How to implement onERC721Received function

Tags: solidity

I am trying to send an NFT to a smart contract to hold in escrow but am having a tough time implementing the overriding function onERC721Received as I get an error about unused variables -  this is the error im getting ?

```
Warning: Unused function parameter. Remove or comment out the variable name to silence this warning.
--> contracts/NftEscrow.sol:11:79:
|
11 | function onERC721Received(address _operator, address _from, uint256 _tokenId, bytes memory _data) public override returns(bytes4) {
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is the smart contract

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";

    
    contract nftescrow is IERC721Receiver {
        
        enum ProjectState {newEscrow, nftDeposited, cancelNFT, ethDeposited, canceledBeforeDelivery, deliveryInitiated, delivered}
        
        address payable public sellerAddress;
        address payable public buyerAddress;
        address public nftAddress;
        uint256 tokenID;
        bool buyerCancel = false;
        bool sellerCancel = false;
        ProjectState public projectState;
    
        constructor()
        {
            sellerAddress = payable(msg.sender);
            projectState = ProjectState.newEscrow;
        }
        
        function onERC721Received( address operator, address from, uint256 tokenId, bytes calldata data ) public override returns (bytes4) {
            return this.onERC721Received.selector;
        }
        
        function depositNFT(address _NFTAddress, uint256 _TokenID)
            public
            inProjectState(ProjectState.newEscrow)
            onlySeller
        {
            nftAddress = _NFTAddress;
            tokenID = _TokenID;
            ERC721(nftAddress).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenID);
            projectState = ProjectState.nftDeposited;
        }
    } 
    
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

You can make the warning disappear like this:

```
    function onERC721Received(address, address, uint256, bytes calldata) external pure returns (bytes4) {
        return IERC721Receiver.onERC721Received.selector;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's "just" a warning - not an error - so the contract will compile even with the warning.

The compiler tells you that you're defining parameters `operator`, `tokenId`, `from`, and `data`, but you're not using them. However, the ERC721 standard requires the `onERC721Received()` function to accept all these parameters, even though you might not use them, because the function selector is determined from them.

So you can safely ignore this warning.

Comment: this is because the IERC721 spec as given here https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721 explicitly says that this method `onERC721Received` will be called with the mentioned 4 params. so you should include all 4.